# VBA eval function returns #NAME? error but only some of the time, how do I understand this behaviour?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the VBA function:

```
Public Function eval(s As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    eval = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

The string I am evaluating:

```
IF(@size<=10,100,IF(AND(@size>10,@size<=20),200,""))
```

It exists in a table like the following:

```
table1:
|--------|------------------------------------------------------|
| fruit  | price                                                |
|--------|------------------------------------------------------|
| apple  | IF(@size<=10,100,IF(AND(@size>10,@size<=20),200,"")) |
|--------|------------------------------------------------------|
| orange | 42                                                   |
|--------|------------------------------------------------------|
| pear   | 21                                                   |
|--------|------------------------------------------------------|
```

I use the above table in the following way:

```
|--------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| fruit  | size    | price                                                           |
|--------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| apple  | 5       | =LET(price,INDEX(table1[price],MATCH(@fruit, table1[fruit],0)), |
|        |         |     IF(ISTEXT(price),EVAL(price),price)                         |
|--------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| orange | 7       | =LET(price,INDEX(table1[price],MATCH(@fruit, table1[fruit],0)), |
|        |         |     IF(ISTEXT(price),EVAL(price),price)                         |
|--------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| pear   | 3       | =LET(price,INDEX(table1[price],MATCH(@fruit, table1[fruit],0)), |
|        |         |     IF(ISTEXT(price),EVAL(price),price)                         |
|--------|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Which evaluates to the following:

```
|--------|---------|-------|
| fruit  | size    | price |
|--------|---------|-------|
| apple  | 5       | 100   |
|--------|---------|-------|
| orange | 7       | 7     |
|--------|---------|-------|
| pear   | 3       | 3     |
|--------|---------|-------|
```

This works, sort of, but sometimes the function produces a `#NAME?` error, in response to some quite strange things. For instance, resizing a row or column by double clicking on the dividing line causes the `#NAME?` error to appear. If I then re-enter a cell which has the evaluate function and press enter then all cells with the `#NAME?` error are re-evaluated correctly.

I thought because I had specified `Application.Volatile` that the function would be executed whenever there is any change to the workbook. So I'm finding it hard to understand this behaviour.

All help greatly appreciated!

PS I know this seems like an odd design choice but for the use case it makes sense. I have some rare edge cases in a complex workbook where this method would be useful, if I can rely on it.

**EDIT:** The ranges are named, `fruit` and `size`, which is why the reference using `@` in the formula above works.

Comment: You might want to use `Worksheet.Evaluate` here.

Comment: ...the default `Application.Evaluate` always uses the active sheet as the evaluation context.

Comment: I'm not sure `Evaluate` is able to process structured table references.  If I just try (eg) `=EVAL("[@size]")` I get `#NAME?`   Perhaps the best you could do is substitute the values into the formula before passing it to `eval`

Comment: I should have been clearer. I'm using named ranges ```fruit``` and ```size``` which is why the formulas work. I've edited the question to include this detail.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: your original approach does work, but you need to include the table name in addition to the column.
Using your original `eval`:

[image]

That's a little less flexible though, because it only allows a lookup from one specific named table.

---

My original answer (which still may be useful):

`Evaluate` doesn't seem to be able to handle references like `@size`, so it looks like you'd need a slightly different approach where you substitute in the value before the call to `Evaluate`

This worked for me: I modified the `eval` to allow it to substitute placeholders in the string to be evaluated with their corresponding values.

```vb
'eg:  =eval("price + surcharge", "price", 10, "surcharge", 5)
Public Function eval(s As String, ParamArray vals() As Variant) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Long
    If Not IsMissing(vals) Then
        For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals) Step 2
            s = Replace(s, vals(i), vals(i + 1)) 'replace placeholder in string with value
        Next i
    End If
    eval = Evaluate(s) 'really need a specific sheet reference here....
End Function
```

Setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You don't need to use a table if ranges are named. I should have been clearer. ```F2:F4``` would be ```fruit```, ```G2:G4``` would be ```size``` for instance. The issue is not that the method doesn't work at all, it's that it sometimes unexpectedly produces errors.